# How can I filter ping results by time?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, ping

How do I filter out any pings that are under a certain ms, ie, only echo ping responses above 500ms to the text file?

```
IP=$1
SECONDS_Between_Pings=$2

ping -i $2 $1 | while read pong; do echo $(date) $pong; done >> ~/Downloads/pings_file_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`grep` with extended regex:

```
ping ... | grep --line-buffered -E 'time=([0-9]{4}|[5-9][0-9]{2})' | ...
```

This will match any line with `time=` followed immediately by either:

- Any 4 digits (1000+ ms).
- One digit 5-9 followed by any 2 digits (500-999 ms).

`--line-buffered` works around [issues caused by `grep`'s default output buffering](http://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/how-to-fix-stdio-buffering.html) when used in a pipe chain. Not needed when grep is the last link in the chain.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried this, and it works by itself, but my answer needs to be incorporated into the code above.  I tried `ping -i $2 $1 | grep -E 'time=([0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{2})' | while read pong; do echo $(date) $pong; done >> ~/Downloads/pings_over100_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).txt`  but it didn't do anything, even when i forced the response time above 100ms.
"

Comment: @Jason Updated answer.

Comment: awesome glibdud!  thanks for that.  it's all working now.

Comment: Be warned that "time" might be replaced by a translation depending on the current locale. (To me it says "Réponse de 172.217.7.207 : octets=32 temps=57 ms TTL=54" while in a French environment.) So I suggest to delete "time" in the pattern, which should be enough if your ping doesn't send more than 500 bytes, else you could append ` *ms` to the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
ping -i "$2" "$1" | while read pong; do echo $(date) "$pong" ; done \
  | perl -ne 'print if (/time=([0-9.]+)/)[0] > .5' >> ~/Downloads/...
```

Explanation:
- `([0-9.]+)` matches the decimal number after `time=` and remembers it
- (...)[0] returns the first element of the given list (needed to switch from list to scalar)